# Trying to check if object has a list and assert if not

Tags: python, function, oop, sqlalchemy, assert

*Question:* I am trying to debug a function in a `class` to make sure a list is implemented and if not, I want an error to be thrown up. I am new to programming and am trying to figure how to effectively add an `assert` for the debugging purposes mentioned above.

In the method body of `class BaseAPI()` I have to iterate over the list and call `retrieve_category` for each item in ConvenienceAPI(BaseAPI), passing the new list on your `super()`. I think that I am doing something wrong because I get the error: `TypeError: create_assessment() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category'`

*Question 2*
I also want `category` to have a list to hold multiple categories (strings). This is not happening right now. The list in the method is not being iterated or created. I am unsure... see the traceback error below.

*CODE*

## instantiating a list of `categories`:

```
api = BaseAPI()
api.create_assessment('Situation Awareness', 'Developing better skills', 'baseball', 'this is a video','selecting and communicating options', category=['Leadership', 'Decision-Making', 'Situation Awareness', 'Teamwork and Communication'])
```

## BaseAPI() method where `assert`  and `create` lives

```
class BaseAPI(object):

    def create_assessment(self, name, text, user, video, element, category):     
        category = [] # Trying to check if category isn't a list
        assert category, 'Category is not a list'
        new_assessment = Assessment(name, text, user, video, element, category)
        self.session.add(new_assessment)
        self.session.commit()
```

## NEW ADD TO iterate through list but still gives `Error`!

```
class ConvenienceAPI(BaseAPI):          
    def create_assessment(self, name, text, username, videoname, element_text, category_name):
        user = self.retrieve_user(username)
        video = self.retrieve_video(videoname) 
        element = self.retrieve_element(element_text)
        categories = self.retrieve_category(category_name)
            for items in categories: # < ==== added 
            return categories # < ==== added 
        return super(ConvenienceAPI, self).create_assessment(name, text, user, video, element, categories)
```

## Table

```
class Assessment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'assessments'
    #some code

    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('categories.category_id'))  
    category = relationship('AssessmentCategoryLink', backref='assessments')


    def __init__(self, name, text, user, video, element, category): # OBJECTS !!
        #some code
        self.category = []
```

## TracebackError

```
ERROR: db.test.test.test1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/Users/ack/code/venv/NotssDB/notssdb/test/test.py", line 69, in test1
    api.create_assessment('Situation Awareness', 'Developing better skills', 'baseball', 'this is a video','selecting and communicating options', category=['Leadership', 'Decision-Making', 'Situation Awareness', 'Teamwork and Communication'])
TypeError: create_assessment() got an unexpected keyword argument 'category'
```

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback?

Comment: @AnandSKumar added !

Comment: Can you try printing - `print(type(api))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your assert statement should be:

```
assert isinstance(category, list)
```

Remove the category = [] line as well.

Comment: How about adding the list though? The BaseAPI needs to create a list and the super in the inheritance class needs to push the list though. Maybe add `new_assessment = Assessment(name, text, user, video, element, category=[])`

Comment: Can you explain better what you're trying to do. What you  have here doesn't make much sense to me. You are calling the super method with "category=[]" so it necessarily will be a list.

Answer (score 0):

You pass category as kwarg, but method signature expects it as positional arg.
Try to change method signature to

```
class BaseAPI(object):
    def create_assessment(self, name, text, user, video, element, category=[]):
```

or call it with positional arg

```
return super(ConvenienceAPI, self).create_assessment(
    name, text, user, video, element, category=category
)
```